# fill the area with color in time series jfreechart

Tags: colors, jfreechart, time-series, fill, timeserieschart

I am trying to generate a time series with the area underneath filled with color.

Looking at examples of the jfreechart library there is this method:

```
ChartFactory.createAreaChart(...)
```

However the dataset required is a Category dataset, something quite different from the Time Series Dataset that I currently create:

```
ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...)
```

Which methods should I use to fill with color the area underneath the plotted line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following after you create the a chart (using `createTimeSeriesChart`)

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setRenderer(new XYAreaRenderer());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GrahamA !

Any may I add that I just found out you can use these lines of code to set your own color (written in scala language):

inline `val areaRenderer = new XYAreaRenderer();`
    areaRenderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.green);
    plot.setRenderer(areaRenderer);